# mcamara/laravel-localization is changing my assets (css, js, others) route

Tags: laravel, layout, laravel-5, laravel-localization

I'm using `mcamara/laravel-localization` on my project everything is working perfectly, but when I'm trying to a layout (`ressources/views/layouts`) to include all my pages the localization is also affecting my assets, the css ans js files are not loading, it's giving `localhost/en/assets/css/style.css` instead of `localhost/assets/css/style.css`. What should I do?

One crazy thing is if I don't use a layout I'm not getting that problem. Help me please.

Comment: I'm not sure what layout you are talking about, but I've had no problem with css or js files

Comment: How are you defining your assets? Try {{ asset('path/to/your/file') }}, in this way you'll get correct asset url.